# jquery ajax success functions not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a modal dialog form that submits data to a table.  I want to give the user some feedback on the success/failure of the submission, but the success handlers aren't firing.

My code is

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "includes/phpscripts.php?action=submitWiki",
  data: {"name": location, "location": locationName, "text": locationText, "user": userId},
  beforeSend: function(x){
    if (x && x.overrideMimeType){
      x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    }
  },
  async: false
}).done(function(data){
  if (data == "failure"){
    $("#submissionFailure").dialog("open");
  } else {
    $("#submissionSuccess").dialog("open");
    var count= 3;
    var id= setInterval(function(){
      count--;
      if (count == 0)
        $("#submissionSuccess").dialog("close");
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

Another version had the if/else block within `done` defined as

```
success: function(data){
  if (data == "failure"){
    $("#submissionFailure").dialog("open");
  } else {
    $("#submissionSuccess").dialog("open");
    var count= 3;
    var id= setInterval(function(){
      count--;
      if (count == 0)
        $("#submissionSuccess").dialog("close");
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

In Firebug, I can clearly see the return from the request is `success` due to an echo statement, but the success function is getting skipped over.  I've set the breakpoint directly on the `done` line, and everything gets skipped over.

In addition, the posts are being recorded into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your missing "dataType" which defaults to HTML/String or XML maybe I cant remember which one off the top of my head, but lets say your working with JSON, if the dataType: isn't set to JSON it won't interpret your backends feedback as valid and essentially will ignore it. so under `type: "POST"` put `dataType:"json"`

Comment: "but lets say your working with JSON" - Why? There's nothing in the question to indicate that they are.

Comment: well your right, other than the `x.overrideMimeType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");` line...

Answer (score 0):

Like Chris ^ told you, add the datatype, then change this line

```
data: {"name": location, "location": locationName, "text": locationText, "user": userId}
```

To that

```
data: {name: "location", location: "locationName", text: "locationText", user: "userId"}
```

The quotes should be around the second parameters, unless they are variables. First parameters can be left like that.

Comment: Using quotes around the keys on an object won't affect anything, either way is valid.